# Сложение строк в датафрейме (каждая с каждой) без использования цикла

Tags: r

Необходимо "размножить" датафрейм путем сложения каждой с каждой строки и записью результата в новый датафрейм. В результате получается громадное число строк по сравнению с исходным датафреймом, поэтому хотелось бы обойтись без цикла, решив, например, с помощью apply. Датафрейм к примеру:

1 3 6
2 2 4
5 1 2
6 4 1

В данном примере в итоге получится 6 новых строк (после удаления дубликатов, либо линейно зависимых строк)
Решить вроде бы нетрудно, но возникает проблема в дальнейшем со "склейкой", без цикла не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то это может сделать функция `combn`

```
# создаем датафрейм
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 2, 5, 6),
                 v2 = c(3, 2, 1, 4),
                 v3 = c(6, 4, 2, 1))

# получаем матрицу с суммами
cm <- combn(1:nrow(df), 2, function(x){unlist(df[x[1],]+df[x[2],])})

# а это датафрейм исходной структуры
data.frame(t(cm))

  X1 X2 X3
1  3  5 10
2  6  4  8
3  7  7  7
4  7  3  6
5  8  6  5
6 11  5  3
```